# Change Textbox Background When it Receives Focus (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

I want to reset the background image of a textbox when it receives focus.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If 'reset' means to clear out the background-image permanently, you'll need to manipulate the CSS via javascript events.

For example, if you use jQuery - you can do this:

```
$('input#some_id').focus(
  function(){ 
    $(this).css('background-image', 'none'); 
  }
);
```

Other JS libraries have similar functionality.  If you aren't yet using a JS library, you may want to seriously consider it.

If you simply need to 'reset' temporarily until the focus leaves, you can use the ':focus' css pseudoclass like this:

```
input#some_id:focus
{
    background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$("input").focus(function(){
    $("input").css("background-color","#FFFFCC"); //adjust for background-image
});
$("input").blur(function(){
    $("input").css("background-color","#ffffff"); //adjust for background-image
});
```